# Find the area of the surface obtained by revolving the given curve about the indicated axis.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$y=25-x^2,$ $x\in[0,5)$, around the $y$-axis

I know that the surface area formula is $S=2\pi$ times the integral of $f(x)$ times the square root of $1+[f'(x)] dx$  I am having a hard time with this problem. If anyone could help me that would be great.

Comment: Since the graph is revolved around the $y$-axis you need a different formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $S = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{25} 2\pi\cdot x\cdot \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}dy$,

$x = \sqrt{25-y}$

Comment: It can be calculated whit out integral. Perhaps he need that.

Comment: I have gotten to that point with the integral and plugging things in... i just am having trouble evaluating the actual integral

Comment: hint: make a change of variable.

Comment: u-sub? I am not sure what you meant about that